# Obj-C objects has two pointers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers

[image]

What difference between first and second pointer?

Comment: The first pointer points to the address of the object, the second pointer points to the address of the first pointer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`object` is a variable that points to a `NSObject` instance.  That instance is located in memory at the address you mark #2.

But, the variable itself has to exist somewhere and it's located at the address you mark #1.

Or, to look at it another way, you can write `NSObject *object;`.  The content of `object` is address #2, but the location of `object` is address #1.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding image for clarity

`address1` is the address of the variable `obejct` and `address2` is the address of the content of variable `object'

Or you can say that at `address1` we have stored `address2` as a value

[image]